# How to parse YAML with SnakeYaml low-level API like getAsInt?

Tags: java, snakeyaml

The SnakeYaml docs provide examples how to de-serialize YAML into Java Class.

I'm looking for simple low-level API that's similar to GSON `getAsInt`, does SnakeYaml support that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use SnakeYaml's `load` method on a `Yaml` object created without specifying a representation type, you will get a data structure composed of `List` and `Map` collections, with the "values" represented as instances of `String`, `Integer` and so on.

It sounds like that is close to what you are looking for.